# How can I show updates with gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want on my webserver a script that checks automatical over cron if there are gem updates without installing updates. I don't find anything about this task in the gem docs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the [`outdated`](http://wiki.vpslink.com/HOWTO:_installing,_updating_and_removing_rubygems#Outdated) command:

```
gem outdated
```